# List all checked out items in repository

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps we have our source code in various repositories.  I to be able to look across a repository and determine who all has items checked out.

I've researched the internet and found nothing.  I've tried install various add-ins into Visual Studio and nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you about TFVC, you can use [TF.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) with [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/status-command?view=azure-devops) command.
Examples:

1. For Azure DevOps Services:

```
tf vc status $/<TeamProjectName> /collection:https://<org_name>.visualstudio.com /recursive'
```

2. For Azure DevOps Server:

```
tf vc status $/<TeamProjectName> /collection:http://<servername>:8080/<collectionname> /recursive'
```

However, there are some problems with workspaces. If your developers use local workspaces, you will not find any checkouts.

Comment: If you have sufficient permissions you can run `tf tc status $/ /recursive` to query all projects in a single call.